# Cordova opens startPage in Safari instead of in the app

Tags: ios, cordova

I created a new Cordova project and put my URL in AppDelegate.m:

```
// Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
// If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
self.viewController.startPage = @"http://mySite/";
```

When I launch the app in the Simulator, it launches and then opens my url in safari instead of in the app.

Why does it happen?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I missed was to add the line:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

in the `config.xml` file, under tag `<widget>`.

Comment: Putting a start page means to navigate from the index.html to the start page. You need to allow navigation in the app for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's a little unclear to me what you're trying to achieve:
Either trying to get to the first HTML page in your app that's in the www folder in your Cordova project, or trying to get to a web site that isn't part of your app but hosted on a web server.

For the later situation, it's dangerous to run external code in your app which is why. To have a web site load so it appears as if it's in your app, you can use the In-App Browser Plugin:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

For the former situation, if your start HTML file in the www folder is called say "index.html", then all you'll need is `<content src="index.html" />` in your config.xml file.